# How to change html, body in CSS to class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a swiper vertical where in CSS there is `html, body` how do I change `html, body` to class?
I've tried changing the `html,body` to class but when it is run on the screen nothing appears but only white color, how do I fix it?
With `html,body`
[image: With html,body]
With class
[image: With class]
In the previous .feature class the class was body, I managed to change it, but I couldn't change it in `html,body`

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  direction: "vertical",
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.feature {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-feature {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-40%, -30%);
  transform: translate(-40%, -30%);
}

.title-icon {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  ;
}

.desc-icon {
  text-align: right;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: Poppins;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<!-- Swiper -->

<div class="feature swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-logo" src="image/eat.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-feature">
            <h3 class="title-icon">Eat & Come</h3>
            <p class="desc-icon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _" I've tried changing the html,body to class"_ Could you show us what you actually tried?

Comment: Not sure if the `position:relative` is important here for the slider to work correctly. If it is, then you will likely have to add another wrapper element around the whole thing, and apply it to that. As for the height - a height in percentage only works, if _all_ ancestor elements have an explicit height as well. You might get better results here if you use `100vh` instead. Apply that either to the new wrapper element, or if the relative position turns out not to be necessary, it will probably also work if you apply that height to `.swiper`, instead of the current 100%.

Comment: Note that unless you're supporting some seriously old browsers, all of the vendor prefixes you've included are unnecessary.

Comment: wow, thank you bro, you help me, its work , thank so muich, have a nice day.